# Python Pandas: Passing previous, current and next row to a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a function that I want to apply elementwise.
Of course I can iterate over the dataframe but this is very slow and I want to find a quicker way.

My dataframe:

```
  A  B  C  D pattern
  4  4  5  6       0
  6  4  1  2       0
  5  2  2  1       0
  5  6  7  9       0
```

My function takes three rows as an input and returns a value that I want to store in the pattern column of current_row.

```
def findPattern(previous_row, current_row, next_row):
   .....
   return "pattern"
```

How can I apply this function to my dataframe without iterating over it with a for loop?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: If it's one column, use `df[c].shift` to construct multiple columns with those previous and next values, then operate by column. If it's multiple columns, then I think `df[c].rolling` would be more helpful.